How to convert bayer raw10 to H.264 using GStreamer?
I'm trying to create a gstreamer pipeline to transcode bayer raw10 frames to H.264 using appsrc. Here's what my pipeline looks like:
r#"appsrc name=src is-live=true block=true caps="video/x-bayer,format=bggr10,framerate=10/1,width=1920,height=1080" !
                        bayer2rgb !
                        videoconvert !
                        video/x-raw,format=NV12,width=1920,height=1080 !
                        nvvidconv !
                        video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=NV12,width=1920,height=1080 !
                        nvv4l2h264enc insert-sps-pps=true maxperf-enable=1 !
                        h264parse !
                        appsink name=sink emit-signals=true sync=false caps="video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream""#

But I keep getting a caps non-negotiated error from GStreamer:
[ERROR farm_ng_stream::video::stream_decoder] Error { structure: Some(GstMessageError { gerror: (GError) ((GError*) 0xffff84022aa0), debug: (gchararray) "gstbasesrc.c(3072): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline1/GstAppSrc:src:\nstreaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)", details: Structure(details { flow-return: (gint) -4 }) }), source: Some((Object { inner: TypedObjectRef { inner: 0xffff9823bd90, type: GstAppSrc } }, "src")), error: Error { domain: gst-stream-error-quark, code: 1, message: "Internal data stream error." }, debug: Some("gstbasesrc.c(3072): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline1/GstAppSrc:src:\nstreaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)"), details: Some(details { flow-return: (gint) -4 }) }

For context, I'm trying to run this from a NVIDIA Jetson Xavier, using Jetpack 5.1.1
I have a luxonis oak-d camera and this is my depthai pipeline:
void add_to_pipeline_rgb(
    std::shared_ptr<dai::Pipeline> pipeline,
    ColorStreamOptions const &options,
    bool data_campaign) {

  // Disable the watchdog timeout to prevent the device from resetting
  // during extended periods of inactivity. Our application has its own logic
  // for handling device drop and recovery independently, rendering the
  // watchdog timeout redundant and potentially disruptive.
  setenv("DEPTHAI_WATCHDOG", "0", 1); // Disable watchdog timeout)

  auto xout_rgb = pipeline->create<dai::node::XLinkOut>();
  xout_rgb->setStreamName(std::string(options.queue_name));

  auto cam = pipeline->create<dai::node::ColorCamera>();

  cam->setBoardSocket(to_camera_board_socket(options.camera_board_socket));
  cam->setResolution(to_sensor_resolution(options.resolution));
  cam->setFps(options.fps);

  if (data_campaign) {
    cam->setRawOutputPacked(true); // Ensure raw output is packed
    cam->raw.link(xout_rgb->input);
  } else {
      auto encoder = pipeline->create<dai::node::VideoEncoder>();

      encoder->setDefaultProfilePreset(
          30, to_encoder_profile(options.encoder_options.profile));
      encoder->setBitrateKbps(options.encoder_options.cbr_preferred_bitrate_kbps);
      encoder->setRateControlMode(
          to_rate_control_mode(options.encoder_options.rate_control_mode));
      encoder->setQuality(options.encoder_options.vbr_or_mjpeg_quality);
      encoder->setKeyframeFrequency(options.encoder_options.frames_per_keyframe);

      cam->video.link(encoder->input);
      encoder->bitstream.link(xout_rgb->input);

    auto xin_control = pipeline->create<dai::node::XLinkIn>();
    xin_control->setStreamName(std::string(options.queue_name) + "/control");
    xin_control->out.link(cam->inputControl);
  }
}

I am confident I'm outputing bayer raw10 frames. Additionally, if I try to run my pipeline via CLI I get no errors:
GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 -v \
appsrc name=src is-live=true block=true caps="video/x-bayer,format=bggr10,framerate=10/1,width=1920,height=1080" ! \
bayer2rgb ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=NV12,width=1920,height=1080 ! \
nvvidconv ! "video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=NV12,width=1920,height=1080" ! \
nvv4l2h264enc insert-sps-pps=true maxperf-enable=1 ! \
h264parse ! \
appsink name=sink emit-signals=true caps="video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream" sync=false

This is my first time ever using GStreamer, so I'm not too sure if there's anything obvious I'm missing. Any help is greatly appreciated!
I have tried specifying caps, supressing caps, but had no success.
I expect to be able to output H.264 frames.
